# Alfred searching through directories and filenames at the same time

Tags: alfred

Lets say I have the following structure:

`~/DOCUMENTATION/UBUNTU/CHECKINSTALL reference.txt`

Is there a way to configure Alfred so that when I type in the search bar "ubuntu checkinstall" it would find this file?

Comment: You could probably define a workflow which uses `locate` for the search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of Alfred's example workflows is **Dynamic File Search**. Here you enter the keyword or press a hotkey, then enter the folder, then the file. In the images, I've used the default keyword activation of ‘ff’, however you can set up a keyboard shortcut to go directly to dynamic file search. Once a folder is found, press enter to start searching for files within.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

To activate this workflow, open Alfred Preferences → Workflows, click the + at the bottom to add a new workflow and select Examples → Dynamic File Search.