# Smart folder: How to exclude all files and directories inside a folder with specific name

Tags: finder, macos, smart-folders

I create a Smart folder to show all the files created today, but I want to exclude all the files inside any folders with a specific name.

Example:

```
- foobar
- - subfolder
- - - file1.doc
- - - file2.mp3
- - file3.doc
- - file4.mp3
```

**I want to exclude all the files and directories inside any folders named  `foobar`**.

Notice: also the files in the subfolders (`foobar/subfolder/*`)

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.2

How can do it?

Comment: Do you use macOS Sierra or Mac OS X El Capitan? You've added "Sierra" as a tag but I think you should specify the OS version in your question.

Comment: macOS Sierra 10.12.2. I updated the question

Comment: This might not be possible http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132860/smart-folder-filter-does-not-contain